# How to split the following string

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split a string of the following format: Drops 3:6-9 and store them in separate data types one for Drops, one for 3, and another for 6-9 how could I do this? So far I have:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the name, number, and between which lines you want to search");
String input = s.next();
String parts[] = input.split(" "); 
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[parts.length-1];
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[parts.length-2];
int num3 = Integer.parseInt(parts[parts.length-3];
String s = " ";
for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    s += parts[i];
}
```

Comment: If you know the characters will never change, you could use .Substring(start index, stop index); otherwise I would try regex

Comment: You want an array like `["Drops", "3", "6-9"]`?

Comment: Well I would prefer an array like ["Drops", "3", "6", "9"] as I'm trying to search a text document and 6 - 9 specify the different lines, however if that's possible using "6-9" then either.

Comment: So the strings here are bibliographic references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a bit more validation and control over what the input can be, consider using a `Pattern` and a corresponding `Matcher` instead of the simple split functionality.

```
// String input = "Drop 3:6-9";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)\\s+(\\d+):(\\d+)-(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find())
    String name = matcher.group(1); // "Drop"
    String number = matcher.group(2); // "3"
    String betweenStart = matcher.group(3); // "6"
    String betweenEnd = matcher.group(4); // "9"
}
// else: invalid input, error handling left as an exercise for the reader
```

Note that the `Pattern` instance is immutable and thread-safe, so you only need to create it once.  A `Matcher` is not thread-safe, so it's often easiest to use a new one for each input.

Comment: It doesn't always take in drop, depends on what the user searches however, I did just try to use this with the input and it didn't give the correct output.

Comment: You may have been using a previous version; I have edited it since and it works locally (there had been a typo or two).

Comment: Still not getting any out, I copied the code completely with a System.out.println(name); on the bottom to see the output of the name but it keeps outputting the string in the !matcher.find section.

Comment: `> System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(name, number, betweenStart, betweenEnd).toString());` for me generates: `[Drop, 3, 6, 9]`  The `Matcher.group` results will not be valid if `find()` returns false, so could you clarify what you mean by "outputting the string in the !matcher.find section"? I made another edit to hopefully make that more clear.

Comment: It's okay, I managed to get it working with user input, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regular expression to split on a whitespace, colon, or hyphen:

```
[ :-]
```

In Java:

```
String parts[] = input.split("[ :-]"); // [Drops, 3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: how would I store these in separate data types?

Comment: In separate variables? `int numX = Integer.parseInt(parts[X])` for all `X` between 1-3

Answer (score 2):

You can get information seperately.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    String lines = scan.next();
    int startIndex = Integer.parseInt(lines.substring(0,lines.indexOf('-')));
    int lastIndex = Integer.parseInt(lines.substring(lines.indexOf('-')+1,lines.length()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have as simple as that:

```
String s = "Drops 3:6-9";
String[] words = s.split(" ");
String[] words1 = words[1].split(":");
String[] words2 = words1[1].split("-");
String[] words3 = new String []{words[0], words1[0],words2[0], words2[1]};
```

Then you will get:

```
String dataType1 = words3[0]; // "Drop"
String dataType2 = words3[1]; // "3"
String dataType3 = words3[2]; // "6"
String dataType4 = words3[3]; // "9"
```

Answer (score 0):

if the input allows in the form (drop 3:6-9) then this code could work:

```
String parts1[] = input.splite(" ");
String parts2[] = parts1[1].splite(":");

String part1 = parts1[0]; // Drops
int num = Integer.valueOf(parts2[0]); //3
String part2 = parts2[1] // 6-9
```